# double quotes issue in string operation using VBA

Tags: vba

I need to post the output of an operation to database , and the syntax should be
{"body":"The Changes are good !"}   .
I need double quotes before and after 'body" and the output text.
How do I insert a " using string operation in VBA? I tried using """ and Chr(34) , but it is giving two double quotes like below

{""body"":""NGDM has not validated the design changes !""}

I need one double quotes like below
{"body":"NGDM has not validated the design changes !"}
........

Sample Code I used

```
     AtrContPostTX  ="{" + Chr(34)
     AtrContPostTX = AtrContPostTX + "body"
     AtrContPostTX = AtrContPostTX +Chr(34)
     AtrContPostTX = AtrContPostTX +":"
     AtrContPostTX  = AtrContPostTX + Chr(34)
     AtrContPostTX  = AtrContPostTX + "Output Comment Text"
     AtrContPostTX  = AtrContPostTX + Chr(34)
     AtrContPostTX  = AtrContPostTX + "}"
```

Comment: That code works fine for me, how are you checking AtrContPostTX?

Answer (score -1):

Please, try

```
AtrContPostTX = "{""body"":""NGDM has not validated the design changes !""}"
```

In order to check the resulted string, try:

```
Debug.Print AtrContPostTX
```

and see what it returns in Immediate Window (`Ctrl + G`, being in VBE).

If I correctly understand your question, it should return

```
{"body":"NGDM has not validated the design changes !"}
```

Or, if Immediate Window is something complicated, try
`MsgBox AtrContPostTX` ...

Basically, each internal double quote must be doubled, and double quotes at the string extremities...

Comment: Hi  , basically , I need only one double quotes inside the string. But when I use """ or Chr(34), there are two double quotes are printing.  I need the result like this {"body":"NGDM has not validated the design changes !"}

Comment: @Arun **This is exactly what the above code returns!** Did you try it as I suggested? How did you try? Or you did not even try it? Please, try the `MsgBox` checking version I've just added after editing the code.

Comment: Thanks, when i tried debug.print it is working.  One more question , if I need to pass a variable to it and need double quotes, any way to do that  ? for example need to pass a variable ABC and need double quotes after and below that .   AtrContPostTX   = ""ABC"" is not working

Comment: It does not working because of missing the limits double quotes... Try `AtrContPostTX = """""ABC"""""`. You must have a double quote to each string extremities and to also double the existing quote (to make it double...). Or try `AtrContPostTX  = Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "ABC" & Chr(34) & Chr(34)`

Comment: @Arun Still isn't it clear enough? So each double quotes must be twice, plus the extremities double quotes (one for each extremity). 2 * 2 + 1 = 5 for each string side...